# PHP structured variable and User-generated validation rules? User-generated PHP code?

Tags: php, arrays, validation

**Background:**

Henry has an application where he would like to allow a non-developer to specify validation rules for a PHP structured variable.

**Example:**

```
$user_profile = Array(
  main => Array(
    first_name  => "Archibald",
    last_name   => "Shaw",
    sex         => "male",
    age         => "33",    
  ),
  guardian => Array(
    first_name => "",
    last_name => "",
  ),
  children => Array(
    0 => Array(
      first_name => "Sally",
      last_name => "Shaw",
    ),
    1 => Array(
      first_name => "Scott",
      last_name => "Shaw",
    ),
  ),      
);
```

**Goal:**

The goal is to allow a user to specify validation rules for automation: is `$user_profile` well-formed?

The user should be able to generate validation rules, without writing any PHP code, something like this:

```
if
  ( user_profile.main.first_name.is_blank )
then
   user_profile.add_validation_error('Error: main.first_name must not be blank')

if
  ( user_profile.main.last_name.is_blank )
then
   user_profile.add_validation_error('Error: main.last_name must not be blank')


if
  ( user_profile.main.age < 18 ) 
   and (user_profile.guardian.first_name.is_blank) 
   and (user_profile.guardian.last_name.is_blank) 
then
   user_profile.add_validation_error('Error: you must specify a guardian')
```

**Question:**

Is there a PHP library or tool already out there that does something similar to this?

Comment: Have you considered making this a linear rule generation progress (with prompts for entering conditions and clauses to execute if the conditions are true)? It might be easier to let the user build these rules visually, maybe with JavaScript, instead of making them write code.

Comment: Yes. That was the original idea, but it is easier to ask the question using text examples. Plus, a system of building visually would eventually have to be translated into code anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solutions

- [Symfony Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html)
- [Symfony Expression Language component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html)
- [JMESPath for PHP](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You'll have to probably build one yourself.

The Kohana framework has this for form validation, check them out:

```
http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation
```